# List view is not displaying proper Model class item

Tags: android, listview, arraylist

I have a List view that is mean't to display different list items based on the day of the week selected by a user in a horizontal calendar view.

From mon-sat i want to display four list item in a recycler view then on sunday display just two items with different value than that of the first four of mon-sat.

problem i'm having is that when i select sunday two list items shows up as i want but instead it shows the value of the first two items from the mon-sat values.

```
 mAppointmentList.add(new Appointment("8:00AM", "11:00AM","Book"));
 mAppointmentList.add(new Appointment("11:00AM", "2:00PM" ,"Book"));
 mAppointmentList.add(new Appointment("2:00PM", "5:00PM" ,"Book"));
 mAppointmentList.add(new Appointment("5:00PM", "8:00PM" ,"Book"));
```

then on sunday this

```
mAppointmentList.add(new Appointment("1:00PM", "4:00PM" ,"Book"));
mAppointmentList.add(new Appointment("4:00PM", "7:00PM" ,"Book"));
```

*images
[image for mon-sat](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1k2guesu6nVzFF-iXeqYOe24LFETs8-OK)

for sunday
[image for sun](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1PTQVSUHPQtYZiMMra1txgHRmEMUv1sZ-)

current code:

```
HorizontalCalendar horizontalCalendar = new HorizontalCalendar.Builder(this, R.id.calendarView)
            .startDate(startDate.getTime())
            .endDate(endDate.getTime())
            .build();

    horizontalCalendar.setCalendarListener(new HorizontalCalendarListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSelected(Date date, int position) {

            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE dd MMM yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
            SimpleDateFormat dayFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE", Locale.ENGLISH);

            mDate = date;
            currentDate = dateFormat.format(date);
            String day = dayFormat.format(date);

            if (day.equals("Sun")){
                mAppointmentList.clear();
                mAppointmentList.add(new Appointment("1:00PM", "4:00PM" ,"Book"));
                mAppointmentList.add(new Appointment("4:00PM", "7:00PM" ,"Book"));

            } else {
                mAppointmentList.clear();
                mAppointmentList.add(new Appointment("8:00AM", "11:00AM","Book"));
                mAppointmentList.add(new Appointment("11:00AM", "2:00PM" ,"Book"));
                mAppointmentList.add(new Appointment("2:00PM", "5:00PM" ,"Book"));
                mAppointmentList.add(new Appointment("5:00PM", "8:00PM" ,"Book"));
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCalendarScroll(HorizontalCalendarView calendarView,
                                     int dx, int dy) {

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onDateLongClicked(Date date, int position) {
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: It's look like you forgot call notifyDataSetChanged or notifyItemChanged in your ListView adapter.

Comment: Thank you notifyDataSetChanged worked, totally forget, thanks again. how do i set this as the answer?

Comment: That's fine, I'm glad I was able to help.

Answer (score 0):

Please use ListView view holder pattern, follow the [link](https://dzone.com/articles/optimizing-your-listview).
Don't forget to call `notifyDataSetChanged` when you update the data.

Comment: Even better is usage of RecyclerView, what is successor of ListView.

Comment: i'm using Recycler view items display okay, just not with the data i'm expecting.